# How to return a HTML page with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

I have a JAVA Spring server, and I am trying to return a HTML page with the controller, but the problem is that I don't know what is the right way to load the page with Angular. Or maybe I am doing it wrong?

#### JAVA

```
@Controller
public class Login {
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String testLogin(@RequestBody LoginInfo login) throws MyException{
    if (login.getUser().equals("test") && login.getPass().equals("1234")){
    return "main.html";
    } else {
        throw new MyException("Wrong login info");
    }
}
```

#### AngularJS

```
$scope.login = function(){
url = "/login";
$http.post(url,{
    "user":$scope.user,
    "pass":$scope.pass  
}).then(
        function (response){
        // what should be here???
        });};
```

Comment: your java code shows you want to load html page but your angular code shows you want to make a login api call

Comment: Get your template through router and provide your credentials with $http object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must return true or false from your JAVA Controller

```
@Controller
public class Login {
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String testLogin(@RequestBody LoginInfo login) throws MyException{
    if (login.getUser().equals("test") && login.getPass().equals("1234")){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
        throw new MyException("Wrong login info");
    }
}
```

And then in AngularJS :

1] If you are using Angular Route, then use $location.path()

2] If you are using angular-ui-router, then use $state.go()

1] Example :

```
$scope.login = function() {
    url = '/login';
    $http.post(url,{
        "user":$scope.user,
        "pass":$scope.pass  
    }).then(function (response) {
        if(response) {
            $location.path('/main');
        } else {
            $location.path(url);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: It worked, but now the URL is `localhost:8080/#/main` and it should be `localhost:8080/main.html`, I'v tried to set the `$routeProvider` and the `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: add code in index.html :

`<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="/">
</head>`

More info:
[link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)